# Show that $f(tx)=t^pf(x),\;\forall \;t>0,\;\&\;x\in \Bbb{R}^n $ if and only $f'(x)(x)=pf(x),\;\forall \;x\in \Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that for some $p>1,$
\begin{align}f(tx)=t^pf(x),\;\forall \;t>0,\;\&\;x\in \Bbb{R}^n \qquad (1)\end{align}
$i.$ I want to show that \begin{align}f'(x)(x)=pf(x),\;\forall \;x\in \Bbb{R}^n \qquad (1)\end{align}
$ii.$ Is the converse also true?

I believe that we can take \begin{align}\varphi(t)=f(tx),\;\forall \;t>0\end{align} and show that \begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\big(\frac{\varphi(t)}{t^p}\big)=0,\end{align} but I don't know how to tranform this to a proof. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume $n=1$ by restriction to an arbitrary line. Then
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{f((1+\epsilon)x)-f(x)}{\epsilon x} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{[(1+\epsilon)^p - 1]f(x)}{\epsilon x} = \frac{f(x)}{x}\frac{d}{d\epsilon}(1+\epsilon)^p|_{\epsilon=0} = p\frac{f(x)}{x}
$$
as desired. Note differentiability is guaranteed by this condition.

Similarly, if $\frac{df}{dx} = p\frac{f}{x}$ then $\frac{df}{f} = p\frac{dx}{x}$. Integrating both sides says
$$
\log f(x) - \log f(1) = p\log x = \log x^p
$$
so
$$
f(x) = C x^p,
$$
which provides the converse.

Comment: Is it proper to divide by a vector? $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Mike no, but you can reduce to a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the $\mathbb{R}^1$ case instead. This is equivalent to studying the Gateaux derivative, which since this holds for all lines holds for the Frechet derivative as well.

Comment: I mean, this line- Similarly, if $\frac{df}{dx} = p\frac{f}{x}$

Comment: Same argument there: If you want to be more rigorous reparametrize $g(z) = f(zx)$ for any fixed unit vector $x$ and do the same argument on $g$ since the derivative condition is still satisfied there.

Comment: Are you still assuming $n=1?$ Sorry, how do we now generalize for $\Bbb{R}^n$ since yours works for the arbitrary line?

Comment: If we have the converse for arbitrary lines, consider the line from $0$ through $tx$, and apply the result there to see $f(tx) = t^p f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose 
$$ g(t)=f(tx)-t^pf(x)$$ 
So $\forall t >0$ 
$$g(t)=0$$
Therfore 
$$g'(t)=0$$ 
Now, by the chain role we have 
$$g'(t)=xf'(tx)-pt^{p-1}f(x)$$
We can evaluate this at $t=1$ and obtain 
$$xf'(tx)=pf(x)$$